# CSS3 tricks: put several element in a row and take all the space

Tags: css

I hope to put six same button in a row and they have a some space between them, then take the pull use of the row, just like "justify" effect of text, but I could think of it, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could float them and center the text inside each 'button'.

http://codepen.io/the_ruther4d/pen/21e6938ab7ab0536f815c67d4b8927e4/